# Saving data in an array and using it in a different route

Tags: javascript, arrays, routes

In my code below I am trying to make the fullItem array display in a div called "current-items" but this div is located in a different route called "/basket". I used a test div in the current route which is "/store" and it displays just fine. I understand that the array data will erase once the page is refreshed or the user goes to a new route. What is a simple and efficient way to keep my data saved in the array and using it on a different route/page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   $('.modal').modal();

var basketCount = 0;

   $(".btn-add-basket").click(function(){

      basketCount += 1;
     $(".basket-count").html(basketCount);

  var fullItem = [];

  const parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
  const itemName= parent_id[0].querySelector("h4");
  const itemPrice = parent_id[0].querySelector("span");
  const itemImage= parent_id[0].querySelector("img");


fullItem.push(itemName, itemPrice,itemImage);

console.log(fullItem);

  var fullItem = [];
  const parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
  const itemName= parent_id[0].querySelector("h4");
  const itemPrice = parent_id[0].querySelector("span");
  const itemImage= parent_id[0].querySelector("img");

fullItem.push(itemName, itemPrice, itemImage);
console.log(fullItem);
localStorage.setItem("my-items", JSON.stringify(fullItem));
var storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-items"));
console.log(storedItems);



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data in `localSotage`

```
window.localStorage.setItem('nameItem', valueItemInString)
```

In your example, use `localStorage.setItem('fullItem', JSON.stringify(fullItem))`.

Remember, when you need the data you should use `var fullItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fullItem'))`

Comment: Hmmm ok I've updated my code but I keep passing in an empty like this [{…}, {…}, {…}].

Answer (score 1):

As @David said you can save it into the localStorage and read from localStorage once you navigate to the new route or you can store the array as a global variable and use it in the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to make sure that the Array's items are saved in a persist way.
You can either use Cookies, Session or localStorage as suggested by David.

But I would prefer you to use localStorage as it allows you to store more data than Cookie. And also localStorage will not temper with your application performance.

The function below will help you to store items to localStorage.
Also it makes a check to see if broswer support localStorage.

```
function savefullItem()
{
//check if broswer support web storage 
if (typeof(Storage) == "undefined") {alert ("browser does not support localStorage");
} 
else {localStorage['fullitem'] = fullitem;//store full item value
}
}
```

With the above, you have successfully store the full item.
Now, even if many postbacks occurs, your full item value is still intact.

For you to get this full item value, use

```
alert(localStorage ['fullitem'];
```

You can have more insight on localStorage [here](https://www.emmason247.com.ng/tutorial/javascript-persistent-variable-storage-using-localstorage-and-sessionstorage/GGZIGWWZD)